# Using rename in the terminal to remove not accepted Windows characters

Tags: rename

I have a folder full of files. Some of these files contain characters in their name that are not allowed by Windows.

How can I use the command **rename** to find, and eventually remove all these characters from the files name?

These are the not allowed character:

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Any help is appreciate!

Comment: With what do you want to replace the characters? Or just remove them. Do you want to rename the files (and folders?) recursively or not?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'd like to remove the characters and nothing more.

Comment: Different distros can use different `rename` tools;  `rename` can be link to a *perl script*,`prename` – you can check which tool is actually run by running `readlink -e "$(which rename)"` in the terminal. my Ubuntu outputs:  `/usr/bin/prename`.   The executables `rename` and `prename` are quite different.

Comment: This is correct. I have prename. I however used the solution suggested by Alex Luecke and it works :)

Comment: ... Actually, the full chain of links for `rename` is:  `/usr/bin/rename`
`/etc/alternatives/rename`
`/usr/bin/prename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `rename` is the Perl one:

```
rename 's/[\/\\?*:><|"]//g' *.extension
```