# cp: cannot create regular file: Invalid argument

Tags: filenames, cp

```
sudo cp -r "/home/fleamour/Music/Mum's Music" /run/media/fleamour/3732-6531
cp: cannot create regular file '/run/media/fleamour/3732-6531/Mum'\''s Music/Louis Armstrong - At His Very Best/13 - Louis Armstrong; Ella Fitzgerald _ Gee, Baby, Ain'\''t I Good To You?.mp3': Invalid argument
cp: cannot create regular file "/run/media/fleamour/3732-6531/Mum's Music/Various Artists/Good Mood Music/Disc 1 - 08 - The Four Seasons: Spring Allegro.mp3": Invalid argument...
```

What is the correct syntax? I am losing roughly an album's worth of music this way. This is under Konsole (openSUSE Tumblweed.)

Comment: You can use `cp`, but you need to change the filenames to avoid  special characters such as `* ?  \  : < > | "`. I will find a better question/answer to use as a reference.

Comment: More info here at serverfault: [Which common characters are illegal in Unix and Windows filesystems](https://serverfault.com/questions/242110/which-common-charecters-are-illegal-in-unix-and-windows-filesystems). If you're using a USB stick with a Windows filesystem on it, the filenames need to follow the Windows conventions.

Comment: These were ripped with K3b, should I raise a bug?

Comment: You could ask if they could add a feature to rename tracks to be Windows-friendly, I guess.

Comment: Feature suggestion? FAT32 default on most car stereos.

Comment: Related: [Using rename in the terminal to remove not accepted Windows characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225288/using-rename-in-the-terminal-to-remove-not-accepted-windows-characters)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The syntax of your command is correct. “Invalid argument” from `cp` usually means that the file name is not valid on the target filesystem. It may be too long, contain a forbidden character, or be a reserved word.

For example Windows filesystems (FAT, NTFS) forbid characters such as `:` and `?` in filenames, so you can't copy these files to a Windows filesystem. There are several workarounds:

- Use a different filesystem (that Windows doesn't support).
- Rename the files.
- Only store an archive (e.g. a zip file) containing the files. Windows won't be able to unpack that archive.

Comment: Is there a bulk renaming app?

Comment: @fleamour Yes there are, including two common commands called `rename` (with different syntax, so check which one you have). Check questions under the [tag:rename] tag.

Comment: I used krename GUI. Can you add this to your answer. Not everyone wanna use terminal, although this is blasphemous to some!

Comment: Kid3 is perfect for this.

Comment: Or maybe EasyTAG?

Comment: Even MusicBrainz Picard if files screwy on Google Music Library download.

Comment: I get the "cannot create regular file: Invalid argument" using terminal, but Files manager (elementary os) handled the task successfully without renaming anything.

Comment: @daGo That means you didn't use the same name. Maybe you tried to use a name with some shell special characters which you didn't protect against shell expansion in the terminal?

Comment: @Gilles I just used bare cp foldername/* /media/myUSB/backup (foledrname directory contained files like "Screenshot from 2015-12-25 13_11_18.png")

Comment: I didn't know there's a difference between Windows exFat and Linux exFat. I formatted mu USB storage on Windows to exFat then connected it to a Linux machine and I started copying and got this error, the invalid character is `?`.